# IBM MQ deployment on Kubernetes

Tags: azure, kubernetes, ibm-mq

I am looking to deploy IBM MQ on kubernetes. Does anyone have any example or links on how to do this image build/deploy to kubernets e.g minikube?. On the official IBM site , it mentions containerised deployments but using OpenShift but it is not what I need.

How can I deploy this on kubernetes?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-container  It has information about deploying MQ in containers.